# where does git store gerrit's change ID?

Tags: git, push, gerrit

I have git, version 1.9.5.msysgit and am using Gerrit 2.10 as code-review tool. I would like to know where Change-ID gets stored in a locally cloned repository.

After successfully pushing a few changes to a remote branch from my local branch, git push surprisingly gives me an error for the current commit saying:

```
remote: ERROR: missing Change-Id in commit message footer
remote: Change-Id: I197b74458ae304ad512d96c4ac905c6d3afc4da4

remote: Hint: To automatically insert Change-Id, install the hook:
remote:   gitdir=$(git rev-parse --git-dir); scp -p -P 29418 abc.xyz@serverip:hooks/commit-msg ${gitdir}/hooks/
```

Before, I got this error I could push a few changes to a remote without any issues being in the same cloned branch. However, all of a sudden, I am getting this error.

When I checked my local log, I could see that the current commit already has a Change-Id, but git push says the Change-Id is missing.

There are no changes in the commit-msg file which is actually used to generate Change-Ids.

If I could see where this Change-Id is getting stored, maybe I could see the difference between already existing Change-Id and the one producing the Error message.

I read about this `https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/repo-discuss/aq98R4-4TqI` I am scratching my head like crazy. How do I fix this?

Comment: can you please provide the output of git show <sha> ?

Comment: also, what does your "git push" command look like?

Comment: Have you tried one of the following: `gitdir=$(git rev-parse --git-dir); scp -p -P 29418 abc.xyz@serverip:hooks/commit-msg ${gitdir}/hooks/` or `make a second clone; commit a dummy; push;`
`

Answer (score 1):

The change-id from Git's point of view is just stored in the commit message of commits.

Gerrit uses these change id's to associate commits together (as patch-set's) that make up a change.

**Make sure that there is an empty line in-between your commit message and the change-id and that the change-id is the very last line.**

For example:

```
>>git show
commit eafbc99b9343a5e060ece5c95b050c3fc541f292
Author: John Doe <John.Doe@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Sep 1 16:12:17 2015 -0400

    My commit message header

    This commit is...

    Change-Id: I511a54c1ec18e59615d76f89d57c0a7cc03b6f5c
```

You may want to re-run this command (from Git's output), and the amend your commit:

```
gitdir=$(git rev-parse --git-dir); scp -p -P 29418 abc.xyz@serverip:hooks/commit-msg ${gitdir}/hooks/

git commit --amend
```

Comment: I already have this hook file installed and as I said... I could able to push few changes before without any issues... the issue is only with the current commit... when I try to push it, it says... Change-Id is missing...  but my commit already has it.  and yes, I am following the format as you said..   there is an empty line before the Change-Id and the Change-Id is in the very last line of the commit message

Answer (score 0):

The Gerrit change id is simply part of the commit message. So here, Gerrit asks you to add the change id to the commit message so it can link the commit the change and vice-versa.

To do that, simply amend your commit using `git commit --amend`. This will bring up your editor, and then just add the following line to the end:

```
Change-Id: I197b74458ae304ad512d96c4ac905c6d3afc4da4
```

E.g.

```
This is the commit summary

There can also be some extra text in the commit message.

Change-Id: I197b74458ae304ad512d96c4ac905c6d3afc4da4
```

Usually, you would install the commit hook as suggested by the hint in the error message. That way, whenever you commit, a new change ID is appended to the commit message. So you don’t need to do that manually.

Comment: If you see my post... I mentioned that, I could able to push few changes without any issues because all of those previous changes have Change-Ids in them..  even the current commit has the Change-Id when I check my log...   thats why, I said.. its surprising for me that git says my recent commit does not have Change-Id.... but in reality, that commit has it.

Comment: Check the output of `git show` if the change id is really in the current commit

Comment: yes, my recent and the latest commit has the Change-Id...  I know this might sound silly/crazy... but its true... my commit has Change-Id ... i dont know, why git still says that ... Change-Id is missing

Comment: Okay, that’s really weird then, and I’m out of ideas. Sorry :/